mod_fcgid: stderr: thrown in
I changed PHP version for WordPress and started getting 500 error. I reverted it to the initial version, deactivated plugins and themes, but still getting the error. When I checked the server- side error log, I found the error below:
mod_fcgid: stderr:   thrown in /home/.../public_html/wp-load.php on line 50

It seems Wordpress is not able to load, "wp-config.php" on line 50 in "wp-load.php"
I checked the file permission, but everything looks good.
I'm not seeing any signs of Modsecurity blocking it.
I also checked PHP Handler to make sure it's correct.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Could you please share the details with which version of PHP you are getting this issue.

@NarendraSishodiya I'm using php 8 and 8.1. I switched php versions a few times during the troubleshoot, but it did not make any difference.
